# Clojure. Storing two Integers and a Double from User Input into a List

Tags: list, dictionary, clojure

I am trying to store two integers and a double from User Input into a list in Clojure. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

My standard input to the console: 12 1 5.30.

Here is my code:

```
(ns clojure.partial.map
(:gen-class))

(defn string-to-list [s]
  (re-seq #"\d+\d+(\d+)?\.(\d+)?" s))

(defn convert-seq-of-int-to-strings [ss]
  (let [new_partition (partition-all 2 ss)
       map-one (map #(Integer/parseInt %) (take 1 new_partition))
       map-two (map #(Double/parseDouble %) (take 1 (drop 1 new_partition)))
       map-concat (concat (map-one map-two))]
   (doseq [item map-concat]
   (println item)))

(def user-input (read-line))

(def new-sequence (string-to-list new-line))

(def converting-seq-to-list (convert-seq-of-int-to-strings new-seq))

; Expected Output: 
; 12
; 1
; 5.30
```

Error Message:

```
Execution error (ClassCastException) at clojure.partial.map/convert-seq-of-int-to-strings.
class clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn

(clojure.lang.LazySeq and clojure.lang.IFn are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Comment: Can you please update the question with the current code. Also, add an example of sample input and expected output.

Comment: Of course. Doing so now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually much more errors than one `let`, but let's start from that:

- You're missing parentheses around [`let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let) and missing brackets around bindings in this [`let`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let).
- `(concat (map-one map-two))` is causing this exception: `class clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn`. `map-one` isn't function, so you should call this [`concat`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/concat) like this: `(concat map-one map-two)`
- Regex in `string-to-list` can't parse your string `"5 10 2.84"`. You could rewrite that into something like this:

```
(->> (re-seq #"\d+(\.\d+)?" "5 10 2.84")
     (map first))
=> ("5" "10" "2.84")
```

Or even more readable [`clojure.string/split`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split):

```
(clojure.string/split "5 10 2.84" #" ")
=> ["5" "10" "2.84"]
```

- I don't understand why you need to use [`partition`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/partition), so I will skip this one.
- Replace `Integer/parseInt` and `Double/parseDouble` with `parse-long` and `parse-double`. You will actually need only one, because `parse-double` also handles strings without a decimal dot. Or you can use [`clojure.edn/read-string`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.edn/read-string), if you want to get numbers of desired types.
- Your function `convert-seq-of-int-to-strings` actually returns `nil`, as result of `doseq`. And its name is misleading, you're converting a sequence of strings into a sequence of numbers.

With all these changes, your code could look like this:

```
(defn input-to-seq []
  (let [numbers (->> (clojure.string/split (read-line) #" ")
                     (mapv clojure.edn/read-string))]
    (doseq [item numbers]
      (println item))
    numbers))
```

Comment: You are a lovely human being, @Martin Půda. I'm sorry for my sloppy notation and code. Thank you for your explanation on each of my mistakes. I will accept this answer as "Solved". Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the square brackets in the `let` statement. Also, use (round) parentheses outside of the `let`. Example:

```
(let [a 1
      b 2
      c (+ a b)]
  (println "c =" c))
```

Just guessing on what you want.  Here is one possible solution, built using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.edn :as edn]
    [clojure.string :as str]
    [schema.core :as s]))

(verify
  (let [input-str  "1 2 3.0"
        tokens     (str/split input-str #"\s+")
        result     (vec (for [token tokens]
                          (edn/read-string token)))]
    (is= result [1 2 3.0])))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated this mistake on my end. I will leave the error as-is on the original post.

Comment: I am now getting a new error: Execution error (ClassCastException) at clojure.partial.map/convert-seq-of-int-to-strings.
class clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.IFn (clojure.lang.LazySeq and clojure.lang.IFn are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to do it would be using edn/read-string on your whole collection, wrapping it into vector before reading:

```
(defn parse [s]
  (clojure.edn/read-string (format "[%s]" s)))

user> (parse "1 2 10.0 3")
;;=> [1 2 10.0 3]
```